# Django: Running inspectdb command produces ImportError: cannot import name 'NoArgsCommand'

Tags: python, django

What I am currently trying to achieve is to map the database that I have in sqlite3 to Django (version 4.1) models. I have tried using `inspectdb` but it keeps throwing `ImportError: cannot import name 'NoArgsCommand' from 'django.core.management.base'`.

I first tried running the command below:

```
python manage.py inspectdb --database \transactions\db.sqlite3
```

Which gave me the error:

> from django.core.management.base import NoArgsCommand, CommandError
> ImportError: cannot import name 'NoArgsCommand' from 'django.core.management.base' (C:\Users\E.Musonda\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py)

I then moved my sqlite3 to my projects base directory and run the command below:

```
python manage.py inspectdb > models.py
```

Which still produced the same error.

Django database configuration:

```
    DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': BASE_DIR / 'db.sqlite3',
    }
}
```

Installed Apps :

```
    INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',

    #Django Apps
    'authentication.apps.AuthenticationConfig',
    'transactions.apps.TransactionsConfig',
    'user_settings.apps.UserSettingsConfig',

    #Installed Apps
    'rest_framework',
    'inspectdb',
]
```

Has anyone encountered this problem before and solved it? Or maybe I'm using the `inspectdb` command in a wrong way? Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some struggling here and there, I finally managed to generate the required database models by doing the following:

1. Uninstalled `django-inspectdb` using the 'pip uninstall django-inspectdb' command
2. Installed 'django-extensions' using pip:

> pip install django-extensions

3. Added 'django-extensions' to my installed apps

   ```
   INSTALLED_APPS = [
   #Other Apps
   'rest_framework',
   'django_extensions',
   ```

   ]
4. run the `python manage.py inspectdb > models.py` command

At the end of the day, installing `django-inspectdb` was the real issue.
Hope This Helps!